# Taking lot of time to read from SQL Server using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 4 million rows in a table.( size around 300 GB ), I want to read all the rows in the table from sql server database. I used following code in C#. This is taking time. Please suggest me some improvements.

```
            List<int> hit_block_index = new List<int>();

            /* Here i process some other and populate hit_block_index with integers */

            string _query = "SELECT TraceName,BlockVector FROM Trace";

            SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string);

            _connection.Open();

            SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(_query, _connection);

            SqlDataReader data_reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

            Byte[] block_vector=null;

            string trace_name = null;

            BitArray trace = null;

            int max_coverage = 0;

            while (data_reader.Read())
            {
                  int coverage = 0;

                  block_vector = (byte[])data_reader["BlockVector"];

                  trace_name = (string)data_reader["TraceName"];

                  BitArray trace = new BitArray(block_vector);

                  foreach (int x in hit_blocks_index)
                  {
                       if (trace[x])
                       {
                           coverage++;
                       }
                  }

                  Console.WriteLine("hit count is:" + coverage);

                  if (coverage > max_coverage)
                  {
                         most_covered_trace = trace_name;
                         most_covered_array = trace;
                         max_coverage = coverage;
                  }
           }
```

Comment: 300 GB should take time, I'd be worried if it doesn't

Comment: Improvement #1: Lower expectations.

Comment: Switch to a faster line.

Comment: It is taking around 3 hours , How much does it generally take to retrive 300 GB of data from a database ?? , and also is SqlDataReader the right thing to use ??

Comment: What do you do with the data? Hopefully not show it all to the user - so if you're doing any kind of number crunching, you might be able to have the server do that work instead - but we'd need to know what you're doing with the data. At the moment, from the code you've shown, you're just very expensively obtaining the "last" row of data (the other data will have been retrieved but inaccessible and waiting for garbage collection)

Comment: Even 300GB of raw data over a Gigabit link (with no transport overhead) is still `(300<<30)*8 / (10**9) / 60.0 = 42.9` minutes. If you factor the disk I/O, TCP overhead, SQL processing time, etc. into the equation, I don't think 3 hours is very bad at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , I am processing the byte array. Presently sql server and my application both are running in the same machine.

Comment: Oh, in that case, run the `ProcessByteArray()` SQL function on the `BlockVector` column. `</sarcasm>` - if you need help, you need to tell us, *with some specificity* what you're *doing* to the data.

Comment: Next I am converting that Byte Array to Bit array, I am having a List of Integers.

foreach (int x in integer_list)
{
   if (bit_array[x])
   {
         coverage++;
   }
}

I am finding the number of bits which are set as 'true' in the bit_array , checking for all indexes in list_integers

Comment: there is not even any `where` condition so that data will get filter, So 3 hrs I think is perfect for your scenario. :)

Comment: I don't think OP has asked a `Wrong/Bad/Off Topic` Question which results in `-7`. Yes, the solution may be very tough for this.

Comment: Whatever needs to be calculated, you do NOT need to select 4 million rows into application. You can do (and should do) the calculations in SQL Server and just fetch the result.

Comment: Why don't you post your exact code what you do after reading data and your table structure in SQL and maybe we can help you write an SQL query doing the same (but much faster).

Comment: Thankyou ,Please give me 5 mins..I will edit and add more code here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. I'm not sure on the efficiency yet - it may depend on the amount of hits that you're looking for:

```
create type HitBlocks as table (
    HitIndex int not null
)
go
create procedure FindMaxCover
    @Hits HitBlocks readonly
as
    ;With DecomposedBlocks as (
        select (HitIndex/8)+1 as ByteIndex,POWER(2,(HitIndex%8)) as BitMask
        from @Hits
    ), Coverage as (
        select
            t.TraceName,SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.BlockVector,db.ByteIndex,1) & BitMask != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Coverage
        from
            Trace t
                cross join
            DecomposedBlocks db
        group by
            t.TraceName
    ), Ranked as (
        select *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Coverage desc) as rk
        from Coverage
    )
    select
        t.TraceName,
        t.BlockVector,
        r.Coverage
    from
        Ranked r
            inner join
        Trace t
            on
                r.TraceName = t.TraceName
    where rk = 1
```

At the moment, this will return multiple rows if there are multiple results with the same coverage level. You may also have to adjust for a) Some off-by-one errors between my expectations and yours, and b) There may be some endianness issues in computing the correct `BitMask` values.

From your code, you would populate a `DataTable` with the values you're currently storing in `hit_block_index` and pass that across as the `@Hits` [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to read all data ... put your code into the database either by StoredProcedure or whatever your engine allows. It does not make sense to do an full transmission of a database.

Beside this, you should really consider choosing another strategy. 
Example 1: You can create a trigger on insertion. On insertion of a value you can recalculate coverage without reading all data (when it is possible)
Example 2: You can use SQL Azure Federations or Azure Worker Role - to scale out your problem.